# File list as per their usage

Tags: command-line, files, time

What do I do if I want the list of files from some specific directory, as per their usage?

That is, I want a list of files in ascending order as per their last usage with respect to time. In that case the file that was accessed last should be listed first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
ls -l --time=atime --sort=t
```

Explanation:

- `ls -l` lists the files with the detailed list format
- `--time=atime --sort=t` sets the sorting order to the time of the last access

---

Example:

```
$ touch foo bar foobar
$ ls -l
insgesamt 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 foobar
$ sleep 60; touch baz
$ ls -l 
insgesamt 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:58 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 foobar
```

After some minutes:

```
$ touch -a foo # sets atime to cuurent time
$ ls -lt
insgesamt 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:58 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 foobar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 foo
$ ls -lt --time=atime
insgesamt 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 12:01 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:58 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 foobar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Wayne users 0 Okt  4 11:56 bar
```

Conclusion:

```
ls -lt --time=atime
```

does what you need

Comment: `--time=atime` does not set the sorting order; it just sets the time to the access time (rather than modification time) of the file. To actually sort by this time, add `--sort=t`.

Comment: @Jos good catch, thanks :-) I edited my answer.

Comment: It is true according to `man ls` but I can't reproduce it using read-only access to a file.

Comment: I think that you will get the same result with `ls -ltr --time=atime`

Comment: I have tried your command , but there should  be not   -r , because by default it's providing the last access file at the first . with -r this will push latest file at the end .

Comment: @Jos I just tested it by playing with `touch -a` and some `ls` commands

Comment: @Avanibadheka I updated my answer

Comment: @Wayne_Yux Ah yes `touch` apparently modifies the access time, whereas `cat` doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming no filename with newline in name, do:

```
stat -c '%X %n' * | sort -k1,1rn | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

- `stat -c '%X %n' *` prints the files in the current directory with access time (precisely `relatime`) in Epoch as first column, and filename as next
- `sort -k1,1rn` sorts that by first field (time)
- `cut -d' ' -f2-` gets the file name only

---

If you want to get the access time too along with the file name:

```
stat -c '%X %x %n' * | sort -k1,1rn | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Comment: what to add in command if I want the time of file when it was accessed.

Comment: @Avanibadheka Check my edits.

Comment: working well , upvoted .